# How to calculate distance from top left corner (0, 0)?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have some objects (images) on a page and I know the coordinates of them, how do I calculate the distance from the top-left corner?

Comment: Take a piece of paper and a pen. Draw a grid of 10x10. Place a dot anywhere. Can you tell its co-ordinates from the top-left corner? How did you figure it out? Apply the same algorithm to your question here. I can give you the answer, but that's probably not what you need here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this any different than

1. subtracting the X coordinates, squaring the result
2. subtracting the Y coordinates, squaring the result
3. adding the two squares,
4. taking the square root?

In pseudo-code:

```
dx = xposition - xcorner
dy = yposition - ycorner
distance = sqrt((dx*dx ) + ( dy*dy))
```

Comment: This answer would be complete if you add the term "Distance Formula" somewhere. A link to the wiki page might also be nice. You know, just for fun.

Comment: You're welcome.  @Dingo, thanks for the suggestions.  I'll certainly consider it for the future.

Answer (score 3):

You apply the [Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) from your high school trigonometry class. The distance from, say, `(0, 0)` to `(55, 23)` is the square root of `((55 x 55) + (23 x 23))`.